# Uploading image to Google Drive using GWT-Google Picker

Tags: gwt, google-drive-api, google-picker

I am trying to upload an image to Google Drive using Google Picker user interface. So far i have been unsuccessful.

This is the code that i am using :

```
private void onCreatePicker(ViewId viewId) {

    final Picker picker = PickerBuilder.create()                
            .setTitle("Subir imagen a Google Drive")
            .addView(viewId)
            .addView(DocsUploadView())
            .setLocale("es")                
            .setOAuthToken(token_oauth2)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(buildPickerCallback(viewId))
            .build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
  }

private JavaScriptObject DocsUploadView() {
    return com.ip.gae.gartla.shared.DocsUploadView.create();

}
```

I request your help on what could i be missing.

Thank you for your time,

Regards,

**UPDATE:** It seems that my application scope was wrong. In order to generate the correct oAuth2Token, you must declare the scope which you want to generate the token for:

The following its the method I am using to generate the token:

```
private void tokenOauth2() {
    AuthRequest req = new AuthRequest(AUTH_URL, CLIENT_ID)
    .withScopes(GOOGLE_DRIVE_SCOPE); // Can specify multiple scopes here

    Auth.get().login(req, new Callback<String, Throwable>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(String token) {
            token_oauth2 = token;
          }
          @Override
          public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // The authentication process failed for some reason, see caught.getMessage()
          }
        });
}
```

And here it is the GOOGLE_DRIVE_SCOPE variable that i am using:

```
String GOOGLE_DRIVE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
```

So, for now this is working for me. I have attached the solution so if someone finds it out interesting enough. :-)